# Supertest not working with routes that call .render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, supertest

After I add `app.use(flash())` to user `express-flash`, supertest does not work with any route in my app that calls `res.render()`. The test just times out, it doesn't execute the `end` or `expect` callbacks.

Static routes and routes that just call `res.send` work as expected.

In the browser my app works perfectly for all routes.

I started listening to the `res.render` callback to make sure there wasn't a rendering error, and the callback is called just fine during tests with the correct rendered template.

What can be causing the test to timeout?

Here is an example route I set, which doesn't work.

```
 app.get("/test", (req, res) => res.render("dashboard"));
```

And here is my spec:

```
it("at least returns something", (done) => {
            request(app)
                .get("/test")
                .expect(200)
                .end(err =>
                  err
                    ? done.fail(err)
                    : done()
                );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end the problem was that my session store was on MongoDB, and because I was mocking Mongo, it would never get a connection, therefore it would hang.

Here is the culprit.

```
const session = expressSession({
    secret: "double rainbow",
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: database.getConnection() }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
});
```

I ended up moving this MongoStore creation to another module and mocking it during tests.

Comment: Instead of mocking it you could also use the `MemoryStore` for your tests.